# ActivityStreamService responds with 403 Forbidden on SmartCloud hosted Connections

Tags: ibm-sbt

I am using SocialSDK version 1.0.0.20130909-2323 and using the Java API to make requests against the SmartCloud hosted Connections app. I am using basic authentication and can successfully work with the FileService, ProfileService and CommunityService.
But when attempting to use the ActivityStreamService in exactly the same way, I get a 403 Forbidden response.
Are Activities + basic authentication + SmartCloud hosted Connections supported in the SocialSDK?

Comment: I asked someone more familiar with the smartcloud activitystream to answer

Answer (score 2):

this is a known issue on SmartCloud. The ActivityStream REST API's are not currently enabled on SmartCloud hence the 403 Forbidden. These will be anebled in a future upgrade but I don't have details on when this will happen.

best regards
Mark

Comment: Is this still the case today ? Can I use ublog instead ?

Comment: Hmm apperently not, als for ublog I am getting a 403, where for the profile service is works fine...